# How does nested loop works in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops

```
print "\tdog \tbun \ketchup"
count=1
for dog in  [0,1]:
    for bun in [0,1]:
        for ketchup in [0,1]:
            print "#",count, "\t",
            print dog, "\t", bun, "\t", ketchup 
            count=count+1
```

I'm having trouble in fixing this nested loop problem.
Please help me to fix this in a simple way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are **loops within loops**. For example, they are used to enumerate through multi-dimensional arrays with multiple indices.

In your code, `for[dog] in [0,1]` contains a looping statement `for[bun] in [0,1]` which also contains a looping statement `for[ketchup] in [0,1]`

Note that the the outer loop increments only when the inner loop terminates. That means, `for[bun] in [0,1]` iterates once `for[ketchup] in [0,1]` finishes.

Here is what your (triple) nested loop represents so far:

```
Count #1    
dog=0 bun=0 ketchup=0
Count #2    
dog=0 bun=0 ketchup=1 #Inner loop ketchup ends, bun increments
Count #3    
dog=0 bun=1 ketchup=0
Count #4    
dog=0 bun=1 ketchup=1 #Inner loop ketchup ends, bun also ends, dog increments
Count #5    
dog=1 bun=0 ketchup=0
Count #6    
dog=1 bun=0 ketchup=1 #Inner loop ketchup ends, bun increments
Count #7    
dog=1 bun=1 ketchup=0
Count #8    
dog=1 bun=1 ketchup=1 #Whole loop ends
```